# MUI Datatables delete rows

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I'm using a custom toolbar with MUI Datatables and can access the currently selected rows but when I delete these rows, I want to clear the selected rows. On the current behavior, if I select and delete the first two rows (0,1), these rows are removed from the MUI Datatable but the selection change to the rows (2,3).

```
const options = {
     filterType: 'checkbox',
     customToolbarSelect: selectedRows => (
       <MyCustomToolbarSelect
         selectedRows={selectedRows}
         onRowsDelete={deleteSelected}
       />
     ),
   }
```

Comment: In your `onRowsDelete` function, you need to reset all selections to be unchecked.  I'm assuming that you are setting the state of those that are selected before you delete, so revert the state of all the checkboxes to checked = false.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can set a state variable to hold the selected rows and change the value on the `onRowsDelete`:

```
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);

const options = {
  rowsSelected: selectedRows,
  onRowSelectionChange: (rowsSelectedData, allRows, rowsSelected) => {
    setSelectedRows(rowsSelected);
  },
  customToolbarSelect: () => (
    <MyCustomToolbarSelect
      selectedRows={selectedRows}
      onRowsDelete={() => {
        deleteSelected();
        setSelectedRows([]);
      }
    />
  ),
```

You can access an example using class components here: https://codesandbox.io/s/muidatatables-custom-toolbar-hv5n9?file=/index.js